# How to access files with lock icons on a drive that was created in Windows?

Tags: boot, files, windows-10

thanks in advance for any help.

I had a laptop, Windows stopped booting. I connected the drive with a SATA to USB cable, and can see the drive on my new laptop in both Windows 10, (but different Windows installation, of course, I forgot to create the recovery disk), and Ubuntu 18.04 (where the folders all have lock icons).

In both cases if I try to click on any folder, the computer hangs. In Disk Manager it shows  In Windows it also turns off my mouse and bluetooth speaker connected.

Of course I desperately need many files from the drive. I am guessing possibly it won't let me access it because of the Windows user being different? Any suggestions?

Comment: In a command window, `mount` will show you how it's mounted. I generally remount Windows disks (`$target` is the drive, `$mntdir` is where to nount it) like this `mount -t vfat -o rw,user,users,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g),fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks2 $target $mntdir`

Comment: What does all that mean/do please? I am not a programmer...yet. But I learn fast...